# 404 error when clicking on internal links site on the Azure platform

Tags: php, azure

Trying to deal with Microsoft Azure. 
Put a few of the applications and each occurs 404 error when clicking on internal links. In the window says "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable". 
Here is one of them [aska.azurewebsites.net](https://aska.azurewebsites.net/)

On the local computer and another hosting everything works fine. Assume that the problem is in the settings Azure. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the error. My projects were hosted on an apache server, I used the config file .htaccess, but Azure Websites server - IIS, and the configuration file to it web.config. For example, my projects written using the Yii framework, for which web.config is the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Hide Yii Index" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I hope this will help someone